# transparently find file over ssh in *shell* directory

Tags: helm, shell, tramp, find-file, ssh

I ssh'd into a remote server from *shell* and tried to open a file on a directory path that also exists on my local system. The list of files I was able to open using `helm-find-files` was the list on my local machine, and not on the ssh'd system. How can I configure Emacs to be smart enough to provide me the list of files on the path for the remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you use [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). Don't ssh directly through you shell. Otherwise Emacs won't see it. To use Tramp in both stock Emacs and `helm-find-files`, use this syntax in the find file prompt:

```
/<connect method>:username@host#port:<path>
```

For example, if you want to ssh to wdkrnls at 10.0.2.2 port 2222 to your home directory, then write it like this:

```
/ssh:wdkrnls@10.0.2.2#2222:/home/wdkrnls
```

You may omit the connect method if you set `tramp-default-method` to `ssh`:

```
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")
```

Then, you can simply write this to ssh to your remote host:

```
/wdkrnls@10.0.2.2#2222:/home/wdkrnls
```

Absolute path is required in `helm-find-files` for it to offer completion candidates, so you should open a Dired buffer at your home directory to make it an anchor.

If you add your host to `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host host1
     HostName 10.0.2.2
     User wdkrnls
     Port 2222
```

Then, you no more need to specify the username and port. When you type `/ssh:` in your `helm-find-files` prompt, a list of hosts in your `~/.ssh/config` are given to you to select. You only simply write `/ssh:host1:` and wait for Tramp to connect. Successfully connected, you will start browsing remote file system like your local one.

Since you also set `tramp-default-method` to `ssh`, you can simply write like this to connect to remote host:

```
/host1:/home/wdkrnls
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to make Emacs "see it". I have been using the tramp method (albeit more verbosely than necessary).

Comment: Another issue I have is Emacs doesn't give me correct bash completions through ssh in shell mode. I'm hoping the two problems are intertwined and someone somewhere has managed to solve both of them.

Comment: Well if you want such ssh completion, user `ansi-term` for a real terminal emulator. Otherwise, I don't think there is a way except using Tramp syntax in Eshell.